# how to create a highscore in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

so i created a score that counts the player movment

```
    using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;


    void Update()
    {

        scoreText.text =  player.position.z.ToString("0");
    }
}
```

which works fine but when i tried to create a highscore system that save score and display it it just shows zero and doesnot get updated

```
    enter using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HighScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text Score;
    public Text highscore;
    float highScore=0f;
    public Transform player;
     void Update()
    {

        Score.text = highScore.ToString();
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Score",0)<=highScore)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score", highScore);
            highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score").ToString();
        }
    }
    public void highnumber()
    {
        highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score").ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class HighScore
{
    public Text Score;
    public Text highscore;
    float highScore=0f;
    public Transform player;
    void Update()
    {

        Score.text = highScore.ToString();
        //care here, "score" and "Score" it's not the same
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score",0)<=highScore) 
        {
            //HERE YOU DONT WANT TO GetFloat, YOU WANT TO SET FLOAT
            //PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score", highScore); we remove this lane
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("score", highScore); //we add this instead
            highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score").ToString();
        }
    }
    public void highnumber()
    {
        highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score").ToString();
    }
}
```

Think about set a var with PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score"), instead of call GetFloat each time. It's more efficient.

Also I doubt, or at least i think you shouln't to have this Script attached to a gameObject... so remove the MonoBehaviour inheritance from HighScore class, and make it static. Cause u only want a highScore instance true? If you have any doubts about how to do it, and you're interested, just tell me.

EDIT:
Well as you said you need a script monobehaviour to control the text, okay. Lets imagine this 2 classes so:

```
public static class Stats
{
    private static float _highScore; //your highscore it's here
    private static int _maxHp, _hp; //some example values
//...someMoreValues

    private static float _savedScore //this data gets the last score from PlayerPrefs
    private static bool _initialized; //this var is used to know if playerPref data is loaded

    //Calling this you always update your highscore
    public static void GetHighScore()
    {
        _InitializeScores();
        return _highScore;
    }

    //this calls playerprefs to save the highscore
    public static void SaveHighScore(){
        if(_savedScore < _highScore) //only if it's bigger than previuos one
        {
            _savedScore = _highScore; //we also update the savedscore we had from PlayerPrefs initialization
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("score", _highScore);
        }   
    } 

    //this loads your playerprefs values the 1st time it's called
    private static void _InitializeScores()
    {
        if (!_initialized) //if not initialized
        {
            _initialized = true;
            _savedScore= PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score", 0f);
            _highScore = _savedScore
            //here you can add all the vars in a future you could recover from PlayerPrefs;
        }
    }
}
```

this 1st class manages your highscore, and after at the text you have this other one:

```
public class HighScoreTextController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //here you drag'n'drop your text script as always
    public Text score;
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        score.text = Stats.GetHighScore().ToString();
    }
}
```

As you see, at update you call Stats.highScore.ToString(). You don't need to create a var with an instance of it like

```
Stats stats = new Stats();
```

Because Stats is static (no instances, only one for all the game).  GetHighScore takes care of call PlayerPrefs the 1st time you need to show the highScore and gives you it all the time you need.

When you want to save your highScore, for example when the game ends, you just call

```
Stats.SaveHighScore();
```

And only if the score is bigger, it is saved... Calling PlayerPrefs, only one time to get the data, and only one time to save it if necesary.

And why we want to use 2 scripts instead of 1? 
Well, because you don't know yet, but maybe in a future you will need to get your highScore from other site... And elsewhere, you only need to call to Stats.GetHighScore(), because it's static. And maybe in a future you would need to use PlayerPrefs for other values... well you can initialize all at same time at your stats and use them whenever u wish.

Best Wishes

Comment: so i attached the script to a highscore text is that wrong?? so how will highscore number be changed if the script isnt attached to any thing @Rubén Cantón

Comment: and dont i need to attach score script to highscore text and that cannot happen only by attach it to a gameobject

Comment: Sry for the time, ive updated my answerin order to help with you about this. If this might help you i'll appreciate so much if you check my answer with the green check at the top left of it... it would help me so much!

Comment: And at all is wrong to atach the script, just offering other idea for a future u would need the value at other site